# How to securely store api key, secret, passphrase?

Tags: encryption

I would like to securely store an api key, secret, and passphrase on my server.  What is the best way of going about this?

I was thinking of creating a simple compiled c++ program that would encrypt/decrypt so that a hacker wouldn't be able to see my encryption method, would that work?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I would run this on Ubuntu